# Layout issue with Nexus (Text not showing properly)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four buttons at the bottom of layout, it works very well with all the devices as shown in below image

Not sure if it is issue with the Nexus or with my code, any suggestions :

Comment: Maybe try without Table Row. A simple LinearLayout should be enough and why don't the buttons have a height value ? Also you could try to replace Buttons with TextView. It can look the same and maybe will fix it.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, can you give me some examples where buttons are aligned at bottom with LinearLayout

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout that fills the screen, and put the LinearLayout in it with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". Don't forget to always specifiy a height for each view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
android:padding="8dip"
```

And add this line:

```
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

To every one of your `Button`s.

Comment: Then the button height becomes so small, almost impossible to touch

Comment: Check my revised answer.

Comment: I tried your part, it works well but again when phone goes abnormal it behaves weird, i have posted both images in question. I guess it is problem with Nexus more than my layout, what do you say ?

Comment: Ya i tried on all other phones, it works very well only in Nexus it behaves like this, not sure, let me try with Linear Layout. Nexus is a buggy phone

Comment: Are all of those devices on the same API level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80743/discussion-between-christine-and-ridsatrio).